# SQL Server 2017 Linux Docker Ole Automation issue

Tags: sql-server, docker, ole-automation

I've installed SQL Server Developer Edition on Linux Docker

When running this

```
DECLARE @win int
DECLARE @hr  int
EXEC @hr=sys.sp_OACreate 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1',@win OUT
```

I get error:

`Msg 17750, Level 16, State 0, Procedure sys.sp_OACreate, Line 1
Could not load the DLL odsole70.dll, or one of the DLLs it references. Reason: 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).`

Googling didn't help either

Comment: This is a stab in the dark, but that object is called `WinHttp`; as in "Windows HTTP". Linux and Windows are different operating systems. I doubt that DLL exists on Linux, as it's a Windows utility.

Comment: To add on to the comment by @Larnu, OLE automation (COM) is a Windows technology that's not available on Lunux.

Comment: @DanGuzman Is there any workaround?

Comment: @Elnur, unfortunately, no workaround that I know of. A better method would be SQLCLR but SQL Server on Linux doesn't allow `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` or `UNSAFE` assemblies. Refactoring to move HTTP access from T-SQL to the app layer would be the best long-term solution. IMHO, this sort of task is better done in app code rather than the database to avoid tight coupling and external dependencies.